# How to change the checked value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the radio button that is checked by default and I cannot access the html to do so, but I can use javascript. Here is the html

```
<div class="row" id="courseSearchAvailability">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <fieldset class="accessibility">
            <legend>
              Filter By Course Availability
            </legend>

         <div class="radio">
              <label> 
                <input type="radio" name="courseSearch.filterString" value="availforreg" id="searchAvailable"> 
                Search scheduled courses 
              </label>
            </div>
             <div class="radio">
              <label> 
                <input type="radio" name="courseSearch.filterString" value="all" checked="checked" id="searchAll"> 
                Search all courses 
              </label>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to make the searchAvailable the default and here is the javascript that I'm using and it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to this so be nice lol.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('searchAvailable');
sel.searchALL.removeAttribute('checked');
sel.searchAvailable.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
document.forms[0].reset();
```

Comment: What are these searchALL and searchAvailable methods you are calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just these two lines should be enough:

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('searchAvailable');
sel.checked = true;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="courseSearchAvailability">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <fieldset class="accessibility">
            <legend>Filter By Course Availability</legend>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="courseSearch.filterString" value="availforreg" id="searchAvailable">Search scheduled courses</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="courseSearch.filterString" value="all" checked="checked" id="searchAll">Search all courses</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```